# Python 3.4 - (tk/ttk/tcl) LabelFrames Manager

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm using Python's built-in tkinter GUI builder.

I made a function to change a labelframe when a button is pressed. There are many buttons, all that open a different labelframe. If they are pressed again, it resets to the default frame.
I can't post the full code as its far too long, but here's everything you should need.

```
 button6 = ttk.Button(tab5, text="Button24",
                         command=lambda: controller.use_frame(Contents),
                         style="A.TButton")
    button6.grid(ipadx=btnipx, ipady=btnipy,
                 padx=btnpx, pady=btnpy,
                 row=8, column=3,
                 sticky="nsew")

    ###################################################
    # LABEL FRAMES
    #######################
    # DEFAULT FRAME
    group_default = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="DEFAULT")
    label_default = ttk.Label(group_default, text="The selected program will execute here.\n\ntest", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label_default.grid(padx=30, pady=30, row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    # LABEL FRAMES MANAGER
    group_s = None
    def lfm(group):
       if group != group:
           group_s = group.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
           return group_s
       else:
           group_s = group_default.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
           return group_s

    # THIS IS MY SAMPLE CALL TO AUTOMATICALLY SET IT TO DEFAULT
    lfm(group_default).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

I've tried taking out the 'return' from each if/else block, and many other things, but the function will not return a labelframe, it returns Nonetype.

HERE is the ERROR:

```
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/testGUI/gui1_0tst.py", line 1171, in __init__
    lfm(group_default).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

Comment: we don't need "the full code", we need the smallest amount of code that _actually runs_ which duplicates the problem. Write a new program that has just enough code to solve the problem. Often, the act of you trying to write that program will enable you to spot the error yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

`grid(...)` always returns `None`. Consider the following code:

```
group_s = group.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

`group_s` will always be `None`, which is probably not what you're intending. Instead of `return group_s` you probably want either `return group` or `return group_default`.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was solved in my answer from earlier. When I called lfm(group_default).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew), the function returned group.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew") so my code was really outputting: group.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew), which is not valid in any way. To fix this, I only called lfm(group_default) without the gridding. The code works perfectly now :)

Answer (score -1):

AHHHHHHHHHHHHHH I CAN'T BELIEVE I DIDN'T SEE THIS!

I've been working at this for hours. This is too simple.

```
group_s = None
def lfm(group):
   if group != group:
       group_s = group.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
       return group_s
   else:
       group_s = group_default.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
       return group_s

# THIS IS MY SAMPLE CALL TO AUTOMATICALLY SET IT TO DEFAULT
lfm(group_default).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

lfm(group_default).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew"

READS:
group_default.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew"

At least my problem is solved :D

First StackOverflow post ever

New Questions: If something like this happens, will it ALWAYS return Nonetype?

Comment: How can I edit my If statement so that if i click the button twice, it will reset to default? It's not working, but everything else is